# FormCollection binding checkbox selections with inputs in C# MVC

Tags: c#, razor, data-binding

I wonder, if there is an easy way to bind my Checkbox selection with other values, that are later sent to server.

For example following picture, if I select here 3 values (Jaan, Kapp, Taavi), then Server receive **3** (people) values from checkbox but **4** values for dropdowns (see example after code).

[image]

In code this looks like that (Probably not best practice)

```
<table>
        @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Persons.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            bool check = true;
            if (Model.Persons[i].TrainingAttendeeId == 0)
            {
                check = false;
            }
            // Gets person training roles list
            var trainingRolesList = (ViewBag.TrainingRoles as SelectList).ToList();
            trainingRolesList.ForEach(p => p.Selected = false);
            if (Model.Persons[i].TrainingRole != null)
            {
                trainingRolesList.First(p => p.Value.ToString() == Model.Persons[i].TrainingRoleId.ToString()).Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trainingRolesList.First(p => p.Value.ToString() == "2").Selected = true;
            }

            //Gets person costumes list
            var costumesList = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Costumes;
            costumesList.ForEach(p => p.Selected = false);
            if (Model.Persons[i].CostumeId == null)
            {
                costumesList.First(p => p.Value.ToString() == "0").Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                costumesList.First(p => p.Value.ToString() == Model.Persons[i].CostumeId.ToString()).Selected = true;
            }
            <tr>
                <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="@Model.Persons[i].Person.PersonId" name="AttendingPerson" checked="@check" title="@Model.Persons[i].Person.FirstLastName">@Model.Persons[i].Person.FirstLastName</label></td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("TrainingRoleId", trainingRolesList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("CostumeId", costumesList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Values, that this returns is following:

```
people  {string[3]} string[]
    [0] "1" string
    [1] "2" string
    [2] "3" string

roles   {string[4]} string[]
    [0] "1" string
    [1] "2" string
    [2] "2" string
    [3] "2" string

costumes    {string[4]} string[]
    [0] "1" string
    [1] "1" string
    [2] "0" string
    [3] "2" string
```

As you can see, then there is no indicator, for what persons are selected, but only values returned.

Comment: So, you want values instead of their indexes, right?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid I didn't catch, what you mean exactly, but currently it returns Id values of selected value and I can check it up from Database, if it is correct value to send. So it works it that sense. But I would need to bind those values somehow, so I know what value is selected for what person